# Copy Source Code as HTML Add-In for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, utility

I've been unable to find such an add-in for VS2010, I only found it for earlier versions.

Does anyone know where I can find a newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Code4Blog](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/656f8df1-13ae-47b3-8f9a-89bf107c3b2a) will do what you're looking for. I just tried it out and it seems pretty good!

---

Personally though, if it's an option I highly suggest you go with [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) over the Html produced by this or other similar extensions because it keeps the source code more lightweight and easy to copy/paste.

Comment: Damn page is in Chinese. When I use Google to translate it, it messes up the page and I still can't find the download link.

Comment: Got it. Baixar means "download" in Chinese.

Comment: I actually downloaded it through the extension manager instead; but yes, judging by the layout of the page I was inclined to assume the same. :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), which includes just such an extension (along with many others).

Answer (score 5):

You can install the VS2008 version of CopySourceAsHtml (from [here](http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/)), and then manually edit the `CopySourceAsHtml.AddIn` file located at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins` so that both Version elements are **10.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Extensibility xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AutomationExtensibility">
  <HostApplication>
    <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio Macros</Name>
    <Version>10.0</Version>
  </HostApplication>
  <HostApplication>
    <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
    <Version>10.0</Version>
  </HostApplication>
  <Addin>
    <FriendlyName>CopySourceAsHtml</FriendlyName>
    <Description>Adds support to Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for copying source code, syntax highlighting, and line numbers as HTML.</Description>
    <Assembly>JTLeigh.Tools.Development.CopySourceAsHtml, Version=3.0.3215.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bb2a58bdc03d2e14, processorArchitecture=MSIL</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>JTLeigh.Tools.Development.CopySourceAsHtml.Connect</FullClassName>
    <LoadBehavior>1</LoadBehavior>
    <CommandPreload>0</CommandPreload>
    <CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
  </Addin>
</Extensibility>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that if you install CopySourceAsHtml via that hack it WILL slow down your startup time by quite a bit.  It works, but you may only want to enable it when you need it.

Comment: I've just experienced this myself.  My startup time went from 30 seconds to 2 seconds after removing my hacked CopySourceAsHtml from Visual Studio.